# How to make React app that support multilanguage?

Tags: reactjs

I have reacted app and there are many components, and I want that the text will support multiple languages,
I mean if the user wants English then all content of the component translates into English.

I try to add multilanguage in my react app using the i18next library but I found that I need to write all text in every language and store somewhere then use that.

But I want it when the user selects language and then it translates into the desired language without hard code.

like when we write anything in google translator then it translates all the page with the desired language.

Comment: It doesn't works like that, you have to keep separate `json` files to support each `language`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the content of your site to be machine translated on the go, then some browsers (if not all of them) have this built-in functions. Just right click and "translate" the page. So maybe you should just mention about this function somewhere on the page?)
But if you want the content of your site to be professionally translated, then you've got to store it in the db. And depending on the global language state (which could be managed with redux), the content in selected language will be rendered.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two Solutions
The first one (Not recommended) is just to duplicate the App , which means to have a URL for each language: yourSite.com/en , yourSite.com/fr , yourSite.com/ar ...

The second Solution is to use a Language translation library a [translation library](https://react.i18next.com/getting-started) and restructure all the content as Configuration options for the library

the second solution is hard to achieve but it is the most officiant one.

```js
import React from "react";
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import i18n from "i18next";
import { useTranslation, initReactI18next } from "react-i18next";

i18n
  .use(initReactI18next) // passes i18n down to react-i18next
  .init({
    // the translations
    // (tip move them in a JSON file and import them,
    // or even better, manage them via a UI: https://react.i18next.com/guides/multiple-translation-files#manage-your-translations-with-a-management-gui)
    resources: {
      en: {
        translation: {
          "Welcome to React": "Welcome to React and react-i18next"
        }
      }
    },
    lng: "en", // if you're using a language detector, do not define the lng option
    fallbackLng: "en",

    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false // react already safes from xss => https://www.i18next.com/translation-function/interpolation#unescape
    }
  });

function App() {
  const { t } = useTranslation();

  return <h2>{t('Welcome to React')}</h2>;
}

// append app to dom
const root = createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <App />
);
```